# sun.security.validator.ValidatorException while invoking graph API

Tags: spring, spring-boot, microsoft-graph-api

I am getting below exception while invoking the Microsoft graph API by using swagger in the local.

**Getting below exception:**
feign.RetryableException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path

```
  @Override
  public int addUser(String token, AddUserRequest request) {
    Response response = null;
    int status = 0;
    try {
        long time1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        response = graphAPIFeignClient.addUser("Bearer " + token, request);
        log.info("{}:: Time taken to call Graph Api is {}", loggingComponentName, 
        (System.currentTimeMillis() - time1));

        if (response.status() == 200) {
            status = response.status();
        } else if (response.status() == 404) {
            throw new SearchResultNotFoundException("get users not found");
        } else {
            log.error("{}:: Graph Api failed:: status code {}",
                    loggingComponentName, 500);
            throw new AccessManagementException(HttpStatus.valueOf(500), "Graph Api failed");
        }

    } catch (FeignException ex) {
        log.error("{}:: Graph Api failed:: status code {} & message {}",
                loggingComponentName, ex.status(), ex.getMessage());
        throw new AccessManagementException(HttpStatus.valueOf(ex.status()), "Graph Api failed");
     }
     return status;
   }


   

      //feign client declaration
     @PostMapping(value = "/v1.0/users")
     @RequestLine("POST v1.0/users")
     //@Headers({"Authorization: {authorization}","Content-Type: application/json"})
     Response addUser(@RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION) String authorisation,
                                     @RequestBody AddUserRequest request);
```

Same is working fine with the postman call.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb5yH.png)

Comment: any one can help here please?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the tools/utilities that you're using and not with Microsoft Graph API. Make sure you're using the latest Java sdk and see if it helps you to move forward.